# Set multiple links in UITextView within a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uitextview

I have a tableview that will display multiple addresses as well as some other info in the same cell. After lots of tinkering and googling I came to the conclusion that `UITextView` is the best/easiest way to detect links.

My current approach with `UITextView`, however, is not detecting links and I am not sure why.

Here it is:

```
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(Identifier);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, Identifier);

        cell.TextLabel.Lines = 0; // allow wrapping
        cell.TextLabel.Text = items[indexPath.Row];
        UITextView tv = new UITextView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(cell.Bounds.X, cell.Bounds.Y, cell.ContentView.Frame.Size.Width, cell.ContentView.Frame.Size.Height));
        tv.Text = cell.TextLabel.Text;
        cell.TextLabel.Text = "";
        tv.DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.Address;
        tv.Selectable = true;
        tv.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
        tv.ScrollEnabled = false;

        cell.ContentView.AddSubview(tv);
        return cell;
    }
```

This neither detects the embedded address nor allows for it to be clicked.

Been working on this for too long now, took about 3 minutes in Android! Why is this so difficult??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below line

```
  tv.DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.Address;
```

with

```
 tv.DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.Link;
```

And for detecting link in `UITextView`, your `UITextView` should be selectable. so make sure that your textview is selectable and not editable like,

```
  tv.editable = false;
```

Comment: ahh, I found out the issue, I was not setting `tv.editable` to false

Comment: yeah i was just typing that actually!!

Comment: Nice! you can finish typing it and I'll accept your answer if you'd like (not sure what the rules are there)

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, you need to set

```
tv.editable = false;
```

I figured it was set to false automatically, but that is not the case.